# finite etale group scheme  over a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Could I have an example of a finite etale group scheme over a field k which is not a constant group scheme?

I just know that the category of etale group schemes over a k is equivalent to the category of abstract groups with a galois action. So I am wondering what the objects would be like in the left category. In fact any finite etale scheme over k should be a finite union of spectrums of fields which are finite separable extensions of k, and if it is a group scheme then it should have a rational point, but I don't see how one can translate the rational point to other points, so I guess there might be some non-rational point in the group scheme. is that right? an example?

Comment: How about $\mu_n$, the $n$-th roots of $1$, over a field $k$ in which $n$ is invertible but which does not contain a primitive $n$-root of $1$ ?

Comment: yes, that's right, i was just thinking about this. in fact one could take k to be a finite field, then for large enough n, this should work. Thank you very much.

Comment: For $k=\mathbf{Q}$, it works for every $n>2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have an example of a non-trivial torsor over k with group $\mu_n$ in this situation?

Comment: the torsor is supposed to be an etale torsor (i.e. trivialized by an etale covering)

Comment: Yes. Let $x$ be an element which is not an $n$th power in $k$. Then the set of $n$th roots of $x$ is a torsor for the $n$th roots of unity in an obvious way, and has no $k$-valued points, thus is nontrivial.

Comment: If you have a surjective morphism of commutative groups $G\to H$ with kernel $N$, then every fibre is a torsor under $N$.

Comment: @stefan: every torsor under an étale group scheme is étale as a scheme (or algebraic space), because étaleness is an fppf-local property. Hence it is trivialized by an étale covering (namely itself).